# Delete is not working Method Not Allowed (#405) gridview yii2

Tags: jquery, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

This is my gridview, I changed from class `actionColumn` to this:

```
[   'format' => 'html',
            'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'width: 5px;'],
            'value' => function($model) {
                if($model->id == Yii::$app->user->identity->id) {
                    return  Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></i>').' '. 
                            Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>', ['update', 'id' => $model->id]).' '.
                            Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], ['data' => ['confirm' => 'Do you really want to delete this element?','method' => 'post']]);
                }
                return '';
            },
        ],
```

Which gives me an error.

```
Method Not Allowed (#405)

Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: POST.
```

When I changed to `actionColumn` again it was working, but I changed the code and it just gives me an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `html` formatter will *clean* the value using [HtmlPurifier](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-htmlpurifier.html), you should simply change the format to `raw` .

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-formatter.html#other-formatters

Answer (score 2):

what you can also do is this set the buttons paramter in the actioncoloumn see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-actioncolumn.html#$buttons-detail

e.g. something like this:

```
      'buttons' => [
            'update' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                if ($model->id == Yii::$app->user->identity->id) {
                    $options = [
                    'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Update'),
                    'aria-label' => Yii::t('yii', 'Update'),
                    'data-pjax' => '0',
                    ];
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', $url, $options);
                }
            },
            'delete' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                if ($model->id == 6929) {
                    $options = [
                    'title' => Yii::t('yii', 'Delete'),
                    'aria-label' => Yii::t('yii', 'Delete'),
                    'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'),
                    'data-method' => 'post',
                    'data-pjax' => '0',
                    ];
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', $url, $options);
                }
            },
        ],
```

But i would just extend my own class from the ActionColumn Class create a function like this. I understand your code that all buttons should be hidden or displayed depending if the model->id is the user->identity->id

```
protected function renderDataCellContent($model, $key, $index)
{
    if ($model->id == Yii::$app->user->identity->id) {
        return parent::renderDataCellContent($model, $key, $index);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.
I Would use the approach with the extended Actioncolumn class. Because then all links are still working if e.g. the urlCreator function is changed or pjax is enabled for the grid etc.

Nonetheless the reason why the post request wasn't working was correct as soju has written above.